# How to indent a Table in a List in iWork Pages 09?

Tags: pages, iwork

I want insert a Table in a List, but couldn't figure out how to indent the Table to the rest of the content in the List. The Table keeps stretching across the width of the document. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that particular case you could select the table and then open the inspector where in the "Object Placement" check the "Inline" and further down in the same preference "Object causes wrap" should be greyed. Select the rightest case where you get adjustment to the right. Now go back to your table and drag the edge from the left side to suit your text indent.